# Draggable Resizable not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am having some issue with making resizable and draggable work together on an image in chrome. My page has a list of (draggable) images on the side, which can be dropped on a div(the images are cloned). The dropped images should be resizable and draggable. I've written the following Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $(".scrollable").scrollable();
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: 'body'
  });

  $("#canvas").droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function(e, ui){
      if (ui.draggable.attr("class").indexOf('item') == -1){
        var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        clone.removeClass("ui-draggable draggable");
        clone.addClass('item');
        $(this).append(clone);
        $('.item').resizable({
          containment: 'parent',
          aspectRatio: true
        }).parent().draggable({
          containment: 'parent'
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This generates the following code in Firefox, which works perfectly:

```
<div id="canvas" class="white-box ui-droppable">
  <div class="ui-wrapper ui-draggable" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 126px; height: 41px; top: 104px; left: 211px; margin: 0px;">
    <img class="item ui-resizable" src="/images/qr-code/description-sm.png?1328705570" alt="Description-sm" style="resize: none; position: static; display: block; height: 41px; width: 126px;">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In chrome however, the elements are being dragged and cloned, but they are not being displayed. This is obvious from the following code is generated:

```
<div id="canvas" class="white-box ui-droppable">
  <div class="ui-wrapper ui-draggable" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; top: auto; left: auto; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; position: relative; ">
    <img alt="Description-sm" class="item ui-resizable" src="/images/qr-code/description-sm.png?1328705570" style="resize: none; position: static; zoom: 1; display: block; height: 0px; width: 0px; ">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; "></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I am failing to understand why the width and height of the images and that of its corresponding outer div is coming to 0px. An easy solution would to be change the height/width from within javascript, but I'm sure there would be a better solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try adding position:absolute to the container element

Comment: Still doesn't work. This is the droppable container you're talking about, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to specifically add the height and width to the img tag. Without that the div and the image height is being explicitly set to zero(but only in chrome).