# Resize an image in content editable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, contenteditable

How can I allow an image to be resized when pasted into a content editable div?

For example, I want the user to be able to resize the following image that they have pasted:

```css
img {
  resize: both;
 }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>This is some text</p>
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qbh9CGrKzfA/T_wLm3npDpI/AAAAAAAAAAo/iMOpJVleyf8/s1600/lmgtfy.bmp" width="400" height="200" />
  <p>More Text</p>
</div>
```

I have tried using jQuery resizable (listed: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/) but all this does is wrap the image div. This means that when inside a content editable container, the handles for jQuery resizable can be backspaced out of the container.

The above snippet works fine in both IE and Firefox (not Edge, Chrome or Safari).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Go to caniuse.com and search for the resize property it&#39;ll tell you the vendor prefixes you may need for it to function correctly.

It is not supported in IE, Edge or Safari.

Comment: Go to this link will be useful to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212103/draggable-resizable-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: can i use is incorrect. I am not necessarily asking why the current situation doesn't work, but alternative methods to accomplish the same result.